# Properly doing separate chaining in C++

Tags: c++, hash, chaining

My program is supposed to take in a file from the command line, which is to contain a list of names (no longer than ten characters) followed by a space and then age, all separated by new lines. I am to create a hash table of size 10, using separate chaining, with the hash function h(x) = x mod 10, and then print out the table when complete. I am close to getting what I desire, but am not entirely sure of the problem or solution.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

struct node
{
    char name[10];
    int age;
    node *next;

    node()
    {
        memset(name, 0x0, sizeof(name));
        age = 0;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node **heads = new node*[10];
    for (int h = 0; h < 10; h++)
        heads[h] = NULL;

    string currentLine;
    char c;
    int index = 0, fileAge, hashValue = 0;
    node *current;

    ifstream input(argv[1]);

    if (input.is_open()) //while file is open
    {
        while (getline(input, currentLine)) //checks every line
        {
            current = new node();

            istringstream iss(currentLine);
            while (iss >> c)
            {
                if (iss.eof())
                    break;

                if (isdigit(c))
                {
                    current->name[index] = 0;

                    iss.putback(c);
                    iss >> fileAge;
                    hashValue = fileAge % 10;
                    current->age = fileAge;
                }
                else
                {
                    current->name[index] = c;
                    index++;
                }
            }

            if ((&heads[hashValue]) == NULL)
                heads[hashValue] = current;
            else
            {
                current->next = heads[hashValue];
                heads[hashValue] = current;
            }
        }
    }

    for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        printf(" Index %d: ", x);

        node *currentNode = heads[x];
        while (currentNode != NULL && !string(currentNode->name).empty())
        {
            printf("%s (%d), ", currentNode->name, currentNode->age);
            currentNode = currentNode->next;
        }

        printf("\b\b\n");
    }
```

Input:

```
Alice 77
John 68
Bob 57
Carlos 77
```

Expected Output:

```
...
Index 7: Alice (77), Bob (57), Carlos (77)
Index 8: John (68)
Index 9:
...
```

Actual Output:

```
...
Index 7:
Index 8: 
Index 9: 
...
```

I believe there is a problem with my traversal and how I set the "next" node, but I am unsure of how that would cause John to be printed twice and Bob to be removed. I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things I can see straight away:

- Your `heads` array is an array of nodes, but it should be an array of pointers to nodes:

  ```
  node **heads = new node *[10];
  ```

  (don't forget to initialise all the pointers to `NULL`).
- In the case where you're adding something to a list that already has an element, you end up calling `new node` twice (once for `current` and once for `next`). That can't be right. You're only adding one node.

Comment: @iraxeje: A `NULL` head pointer is an empty list. To insert a new element into a list, (1) allocate the new node, (2) set the new node next pointer to the old head pointer, (3) set the head pointer to the new node. This inserts the new node at the head of the list.

Comment: I amended the code and put it in the original post, but now my output does not print anything. Why does this happen?

Comment: @iraxeje: Hard to say (I haven't run your code). Another thing is you don't need a special case for an empty list. Otherwise, fire up the debugger and see what your code is doing.